# Distinct pair of values SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

Consider

```
 create table pairs ( number a, number b )
```

Where the data is

```
1,1
1,1
1,1
2,4
2,4
3,2
3,2
5,1
```

Etc.

What query gives me the distinct values the number column b has So I can see

```
1,1
5,1
2,4
3,2
```

only

I've tried

```
select distinct ( a ) , b from pairs group by b
```

but gives me "not a group by expression"

Answer (score 114, accepted):

What you mean is either

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM pairs;
```

or

```
SELECT a, b FROM pairs GROUP BY a, b;
```

Comment: Now that I think about it, grouping by every column is the same as not grouping by any. And you beat me by 30 seconds. +1

Comment: JamesMLV, grouping by every column is not the same as not grouping by any if you have duplicate rows. Consider the output of `SELECT a,b,count(*) FROM pairs`.

Comment: Oscar now I realized that my query will give you extra column for b=1 (I actually misread it, knowing that you want both columns, I assumed you want distinct rows)…

Comment: And here is a couple of more queries for you ;-)

Comment: Depends on what you want. If you want *any* row distinct on `b`, perhaps the `DISTINCT ON` one. If you want just distinct rows — one of the first two. If you want some particular row, based on whatever criteria you may think up, then some variant of the last one. The one I gave as example gives you distinct `b` values and minimal `a` for each. in your case that would be the `1,1` for b=1 (because 1 is minimum of 1 and 5).

Comment: Hmm.. if you have *given value of column B*, then I'll add another query to the list now ;-)

Comment: Looking at your example, though, I think you don't have a particular value for *B*, so the first two examples are what you want. You want a set of distinct `a, b` pairs. So, first two queries.

Comment: Still sounds like distinct pairs. And now you can add `INSERT INTO pairs VALUES ('SQLand','SQL')`

Comment: oops, columns are numeric ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I based my first answer (which I maintain seems to be what you want) on common sense. But then I read carefully (what a mistake!) and  noticed that you're talking about `DISTINCT b` only, so I came up with more potential solutions. Now that you explained in more detail it looks more and more like the initial answer (first two queries which give you identical results, but the GROUP BY can be easily extended to give you, for instance, the number of times you had to speak up for each land/language pair by adding count(*) ;-)).

Comment: Looks like someone removed his comments… ;-)

Answer (score 22):

If you want to want to treat  1,2 and 2,1 as the same pair, then this will give you the unique list on MS-SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN a > b THEN a ELSE b END as a,
    CASE WHEN a > b THEN b ELSE a END as b
FROM pairs
```

Inspired by @meszias answer above

Comment: of course!  however i was stumped on how to do this before i read this answer. thx.

Answer (score 12):

This will give you the result you're giving as an example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b
FROM pairs
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want to filter the tuples you can use on this way:

```
select distinct (case a > b then (a,b) else (b,a) end) from pairs
```

the good stuff is you don't have to use group by.

Comment: I was very hopeful of this method, but keep encountering a "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error. What are the syntax rules for sorting the columns by this method?

Answer (score -2):

If you just want a **count** of the distinct pairs.

The simplest way to do that is as follows
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a,b) FROM pairs`

The previous solutions would list all the pairs and then you'd have to do a second query to count them.