# distinct pairs plus the number of times each pair appears

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, aggregate, distinct

consider

```
create table pairs (number a, number b)
```

where the data is

```
1,1
1,1
1,1
2,4
2,4
3,2
3,2
5,1
```

what query gives me all unique pairs *plus a column representing the number of times that pair appeared*. ie:

```
1,1,3
5,1,2
2,4,2
3,2,1
```

Note: This is SO question [Distinct pair of values SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330692/distinct-pair-of-values-sql) but with the added "count" column requirement

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is `(2,4)` different from `(4,2)`?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto yes, a=2,b=4 would be different than a=4,b=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    a,b,count(*) c
from 
    pairs
group by 
    a,b
```

Comment: instead of `count(*) c` do you mean `count(*) as c` ?

Comment: Yes, this is T-SQL (SQL Server), maybe for other RDBMS you need the as.